# Which OS Concept should be better in such a scenario

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, semaphore

I am having implementation of a C Code in which i have this scenario

I have a binary `code` which when executed, writes continously into a file called `log.txt` .. Now at the same time i open terminal 2 and run `code` binary again, which will also write into the file log.txt at the same time

I want to prevent this . What my logic is that when First Binary is working and writing to file log.txt, the second executed instance of the binary also needs to write on log.txt but it should be prevented.. What options are there which i can implement to do this ?

I am planning to use Semaphores for this in C programming. But if anyone have other options kindly let me know

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock is one easy option, if it is available in your platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating threads then you need take semaphore or mutex to protect file descriptor because FD is shared with all threads.

Another method is fcntl() uses `struct flock structure` to define and check file locks.

As you want to protect a file beyond address space you should use 
struct flock or semaphore because mutex will not work beyond the address space. for your reference i wrote an application, have a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define printf(x) printf("%s\n", x)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char filepath[30] = "/Users/darthvader/testlock";
    struct flock *new_wt_lock = (struct flock *) malloc(sizeof(struct flock));
    FILE *fp;

    memset(new_wt_lock, 0, sizeof(struct flock));
    new_wt_lock->l_type = F_WRLCK;
    new_wt_lock->l_len = 0;

    fp = fopen(filepath, "w+");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Attempting to acquire write lock"); 
    if( fcntl(fileno(fp), F_SETLK, new_wt_lock) == -1)
    {
      printf("Unable to acquire lock");
      perror("error");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Doing random shit...");
    sleep(25);
    printf("Stopped doing random shit");

    if(fcntl(fileno(fp), F_UNLCK, new_wt_lock) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error releasing lock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Released Lock...Exiting");
}
```